# What should I do to return a fixed number if the user inputs nothing?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

In the first lines of my code have a scanner asking how many people there are and I store it in variable
people = input.nextInt();. What should i do to be able to return a fixed number if the user inputs nothing ?

Comment: That depends.  Does your program absolutely need to have a value for number of people for it to function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (input.hasNext())
    people = input.nextInt();
else
    people = default_value;
```

The hasNext() method returns false if there's no more input to read, and true otherwise.

Comment: I believe this will simply ask to re-enter a value if you press for example the return/enter key.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the hasNext() or nextInt() will simply ask to re-enter something if nothing is given, like a return/enter. Try this out:

```
int people = 30; //default value

String inputAmount = input.nextLine();
if (!inputAmount.isEmpty()) {
   people = Integer.parseInt(inputAmount);
}

System.out.println(people);
```

A better way is to catch errors in case they enter something non-numeric.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many cannibles/ missionaries ?");
    int numEach;
    if (input.hasNext()){
        numEach = input.nextInt();
    }
    else
    {
        numEach = 3;
    }
    System.out.println("How many people on the boat ?");
    int boatSize;
    if (input.hasNext()){
        boatSize = input.nextInt();
    }
    else
    {
        boatSize = 2;
    }
    System.out.println(numEach);
    System.out.println(boatSize);

}
```

Ok so this is my code. I have actually 2 different integers that are found from user input. I need to basically output the default numbers when the user inputs nothing. In this case nothing happens.